# SAS ODS RTF & proc report

Tags: sas, rtf, ods, proc-report

I'm trying to figure out why the formatting of my reports suddenly changed.

I had been exporting a report with 8 columns, all which fit on a single page in a word document.  This month, it decided to put a page break in the middle (so the first 4 columns are on the first page, the second 4 columns are on the second page).  Code didn't change at all.

So, thoughts:

- data in the columns got bigger, so the width is no longer able to fit on one page.  I thought the ods options "keepn" or "trkeep" would solve these problems, but neither made any difference.
- some other sas setting made the column width defaults change.  So I put "width=10" on the define statements within the proc report.  Again, nothing changed.


  My Code:

```
ODS RTF FILE="&REPORT_LOC./&outfile..rtf" keepn trkeep;
proc report data=FinalRpt2 nowindows headline headskip spacing=2 missing split='*';
column storeNum dept sales;

define storeNum / order width=10 'Store Number';
define dept / order width=10 'Department';
define sales / display width=10 'Sales';
run;
```

Comment: Cannot tell what you mean.  How did you 'put a page break in the middle'?  You seem to have truncated your PROC REPORT code in your question before you got to details about what columns you are reporting and how they are defined.

Comment: Did you update your style definition? Or SAS version? I would run a proc compare between a data set from last month and this month and see what the differences are and go from there.

Comment: It's very likely this is data related, can you rerun on last month's data and see if it repeats?

Comment: @Tom - if my table is StoreNum/Department/Sales, a normal table would just have that with all 3 columns next to each other (like a spreadsheet).  Instead, columns StoreNum and Department are on page 1, Sales is on page 2.  My define statements are pretty basic, which is why I excluded them.  I'll edit them into the original post.

Comment: @Joe - I reran last month's data and it is also in the bad format.  The code itself did not change, the style definitions did not change (I'm using a custom style), leaving only something within the RTF structure?  No clue there.

Comment: How are you looking at the RTF file? Did you open it with WORD? Some other software? Did the software you are using to view the RTF file change?  For example if you are using Office 365 it is constantly being updated.

Comment: It's MS Word in Office 365, yeah.  I ended up just converting the ODS RTF to ODS EXCEL instead.